# I'm adding only the last element to the JS array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, data-objects

Here is my code so far: I am trying to create a new JSON object called dataJSON using properties from the GAJSON object. However, when I try to iterate over the GAJSOn object, I get only its last element to be added to the array.

```
 var GAstring ='{"data":[{"bounceRate": "4","country":"Denmark"},{"bounceRate":
 "3","country":"Spain"},{"bounceRate":"6","country":"Romania"},
 {"bounceRate":"1","country":"Bulgaria"},{"bounceRate":"0","country":"Lithuania"},  
 {"bounceRate":"2","country":"Norway"}]}';
 var GAJSON=JSON.parse(GAstring);
 var viewJSON = {
    data:[]
 };
 var dataJSON ={};
 for(var i =0; i<GAJSON.data.length; i++) {
     dataJSON["bounceRate"] = GAJSON.data[i].bounceRate;
     dataJSON["country"] = GAJSON.data[i].country;
 }
 viewJSON.data.push(dataJSON);
```

Comment: Sure. You keep writing to the same properties of the `dataJSON` object over and over. What result were you expecting?

Comment: If you wanted an Array of objects, then create a new object *inside* the loop, and also `.push()` it *inside* the loop.

Answer (score 2):

Your `push` of the new object should be within the loop.

```
 for(var i =0; i<GAJSON.data.length; i++) {
   viewJSON.data.push({
     bounceRate: GAJSON.data[i].bounceRate,
     country: GAJSON.data[i].country
   });
 }
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/cxwf0omm/)

Answer (score 1):

You are overwriting values every time at `dataJSON["bounceRate"] = GAJSON.data[i].bounceRate;`

Try this code:

```
var GAstring ='{"data":[{"bounceRate": "4","country":"Denmark"},{"bounceRate":"3","country":"Spain"},{"bounceRate":"6","country":"Romania"},     {"bounceRate":"1","country":"Bulgaria"},{"bounceRate":"0","country":"Lithuania"},     {"bounceRate":"2","country":"Norway"}]}';
 var GAJSON=JSON.parse(GAstring);
 var viewJSON = {
    data:[]
 };
 var dataJSON ={};
 for(var i =0; i<GAJSON.data.length; i++) {
     dataJSON[i] = [];
     dataJSON[i]["bounceRate"] = GAJSON.data[i].bounceRate;
     dataJSON[i]["country"] = GAJSON.data[i].country;
 }
 viewJSON.data.push(dataJSON);
console.log(viewJSON);
```

## [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/w48kz6r4/)

Comment: Why are you creating an array within an object within an array? Your code makes no sense - that's why you're downvoted.

Comment: @andy you are correct. But i was pointing error of OP. Your solution is best then me. +1 for this.